# Clarifying a linear algebra step in a large sample theory book.

Tags: linear-algebra, expected-value

I'm currently reading a large sample theory [book](http://personal.psu.edu/drh20/asymp/lectures/asymp.pdf) (page 60, last equation line) and have some difficulty reasoning out a linear algebra step. Suppose that $\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{X}_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. with a finite mean $\boldsymbol{\mu}=(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_k)$, where $\mathbf{X}_i=(X_{i,1},\dots,X_{i,k})$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^k$, the book used the following equality:
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left(\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^n(\mathbf{X}_i-\boldsymbol{\mu})\bigg]^{\top}
\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^n(\mathbf{X}_i-\boldsymbol{\mu})\bigg]\right)
=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\big[(\mathbf{X}_i-\boldsymbol{\mu})^{\top}(\mathbf{X}_i-\boldsymbol{\mu})\big].
\end{align*}
Why is this the case?

**My attempt:** Expanding the vectors, for the LHS, I got
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{j=1}^k\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{i,j}-\mu_j)\bigg]^2\right),
\end{align*}
and for the RHS, I got
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\bigg(\sum_{j=1}^k(X_{i,j}-\mu_j)^2\bigg).
\end{align*}
From the positioning of the squares, the two expressions I got don't look the same to me.

Comment: Your attempt should work by writing $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(X_{i,j}-\mu_j)\right)^2$ as $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n(X_{i,j}-\mu_j)(X_{l,j}-\mu_j)$. Then the claim should follow by linearity of the expectation and independence of $X_{i,j}$ and $X_{l,j}$ for $l\neq i$.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks.